# Xorg: set provider source output in xorg.conf

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor

I've configured quad screen with xrandr commands:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0

xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto --right-of DVI-1
xrandr --output DVI-1-2 --auto --left-of DVI-1
xrandr --output DVI-1-3 --auto --left-of DVI-1-2
```

I would like those commands to be auto-applied on X start.
I've tried this `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "DVI-0"
  Option "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "DVI-1"
  Option "LeftOf" "DVI-0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "DVI-1-2"
  Option "LeftOf" "DVI-1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "DVI-1-3"
  Option "LeftOf" "DVI-1-2"
EndSection
```

But DVI-1-* are not initialized on Xorg start up, they appear only after I do `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0`.

How do I tell `xorg.conf` to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

On a recent Debian system, put a shell fragment in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/10custom_initialise_xrandr`. It will be executed as soon as you've logged in.

Answer (score 0):

or add a small script to your .xsessionrc which is sourced by Debian's X11 Session scripts.